# Eloquent ограничение при нетерпеливой загрузке

Tags: eloquent, relationship

Есть модель Turbochargers

и сам запрос:

```php
Turbocharger::where('status', 1)
            ->with(['motors', 'vehicles', 'images', 'turbineCategories'])
            ->select(['id', 'name', 'title', 'slug', 'preview'])
            ->get()
            ->toJson();
```

я получаю обьект в котром лежать turbochargers и данные по связи с ним
 `('motors', 'vehicles', 'images', 'turbineCategories')`
с помощью `->select(['id', 'name', 'title', 'slug', 'preview'])` я ограничиваю вывод из таблтцы turbochargers только эти поля.
Так же мне надо огнаничить вывод полей из связи  `turbineCategories`

пробовал:
`('motors', 'vehicles', 'images', 'turbineCategories:id')`
но мне так же надо полуать и `'turbineCategories:name'`

и так:

```php
$turbochargers = Turbocharger::where('status', 1)
            ->with(['motors', 'vehicles', 'images',])
            ->with(['turbineCategories' => function($query){
                $query->select('id','name');
            }])
            ->select(['id', 'name', 'title', 'slug', 'preview'])
            ->get()
            ->toJson();
```

**Как плучить обьект `turbachargers` с ограничением в связанной таблице по нескольким стольбцам?**

Answer (score 0):

```php
Turbocharger::where('status', 1)
            ->with('motors', 'vehicles', 'images','turbineCategories:name,slug,turbine_category_id')
            ->select(['id', 'name', 'title', 'slug', 'preview'])
            ->get()
            ->toJson();
```

**Вот так получилось выбрать все что мне нужно**
Если есть варианты оптимизации буду рад если подскажите!